# Fail to test react-native ./scripts/run-android-local-unit-tests.sh

Tags: react-native

I'll be bit sarcastic here, but it just reflect my frustration. So sorry for that.

I'm trying to run provided react-native tests. I prepared my testing env according to [testing.html](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/testing.html) and [building-from-source](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/building-from-source.html), with some exceptions:

1. Instead of npm, I cloned rn git repo as npm doesn't contain `./scripts/run-android-local-unit-tests.sh` and other files

I installed 1.4 GB [buck](https://buckbuild.com/setup/getting_started.html) build system and later realized I also need gradle. Why is react-native using two build systems?

2. Then I ran `./gradle build` which built some native jni libraries and welcomed me with some failed tests
3. Then I tried to run `./scripts/run-android-local-unit-tests.sh` but my testing attempt failed early on buck error:

.

```
BUILD FAILED: 
//ReactAndroid/src/test/java/com/facebook/react/fabric:fabric: 
parameter 'deps': Unable to find the target xplat//yoga/java:java.
'xplat//yoga/java:java' references an unknown cell.
```

Is possible to run tests, or it's just some facebook magic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I share your frustration. Nothing works out of the box on React Native. You always have to overcome a couple of errors/exceptions before getting something to work. Specially on Android.

I've also tried running unit tests on the master branch without success. But switching to the 0.55 stable branch did it for me.

```
git checkout 0.55-stable
./scripts/run-android-local-unit-tests.sh
```

HTH.

**Update – Test execution**

```
[viotti@localhost react-native]$ ./scripts/run-android-local-unit-tests.sh
Warning: The test suite expects buck version d743d2d0229852ce7c029ec257532d8916f6b2b7 to be installed
Fetching dependencies...
Action graph will be rebuilt because files have been added or removed.
Building: finished in 0.0 sec (100%) 52/52 jobs, 0 updated, 0.0% cache miss
  Total time: 0.3 sec
Running unit tests...
Building: finished in 1.9 sec (100%) 289/289 jobs, 19 updated, 3.1% cache miss
  Total time: 1.9 sec
Testing: finished in 58.5 sec (150 PASS/0 FAIL)
RESULTS FOR //ReactAndroid/src/test/java/com/facebook/react/animated:animated //ReactAndroid/src/test/java/com/facebook/react/bridge:bridge //ReactAndroid/src/test/java/com/facebook/react/devsupport:devsupport //ReactAndroid/src/test/java/com/facebook/react/modules:modules //ReactAndroid/src/test/java/com/facebook/react/packagerconnection:packagerconnection //ReactAndroid/src/test/java/com/facebook/react/uimanager:uimanager //ReactAndroid/src/test/java/com/facebook/react/views:views //ReactAndroid/src/test/java/com/facebook/react:react
PASS      9.4s  7 Passed   0 Skipped   0 Failed   com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedInterpolationTest
PASS     18.7s 23 Passed   0 Skipped   0 Failed   com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedNodeTraversalTest
PASS     13.9s  4 Passed   0 Skipped   0 Failed   com.facebook.react.bridge.BaseJavaModuleTest
PASS     571ms  4 Passed   0 Skipped   0 Failed   com.facebook.react.bridge.FallbackJSBundleLoaderTest
PASS    <100ms  1 Passed   0 Skipped   0 Failed   com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaOnlyArrayTest
PASS    <100ms  8 Passed   0 Skipped   0 Failed   com.facebook.react.bridge.JsonWriterTest
PASS      8.4s  6 Passed   0 Skipped   0 Failed   com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleSpecTest
PASS     14.5s 10 Passed   0 Skipped   0 Failed   com.facebook.react.devsupport.JSDebuggerWebSocketClientTest
PASS      7.5s  4 Passed   0 Skipped   0 Failed   com.facebook.react.devsupport.MultipartStreamReaderTest
PASS      5.1s  4 Passed   0 Skipped   0 Failed   com.facebook.react.devsupport.StackTraceHelperTest
PASS     14.7s  6 Passed   0 Skipped   0 Failed   com.facebook.react.modules.blob.BlobModuleTest
PASS      8.4s  5 Passed   0 Skipped   0 Failed   com.facebook.react.modules.camera.ImageStoreManagerTest
PASS      4.5s  1 Passed   0 Skipped   0 Failed   com.facebook.react.modules.clipboard.ClipboardModuleTest
PASS      4.5s  5 Passed   0 Skipped   0 Failed   com.facebook.react.modules.dialog.DialogModuleTest
PASS      3.8s 11 Passed   0 Skipped   0 Failed   com.facebook.react.modules.network.NetworkingModuleTest
PASS      1.5s  9 Passed   0 Skipped   0 Failed   com.facebook.react.modules.network.ProgressiveStringDecoderTest
PASS      2.4s  2 Passed   0 Skipped   0 Failed   com.facebook.react.modules.share.ShareModuleTest
PASS      5.9s  6 Passed   0 Skipped   0 Failed   com.facebook.react.modules.storage.AsyncStorageModuleTest
PASS      2.6s  9 Passed   0 Skipped   0 Failed   com.facebook.react.modules.timing.TimingModuleTest
PASS     10.1s  9 Passed   0 Skipped   0 Failed   com.facebook.react.packagerconnection.JSPackagerClientTest
PASS      8.7s  4 Passed   0 Skipped   0 Failed   com.facebook.react.uimanager.MatrixMathHelperTest
PASS     11.0s  2 Passed   0 Skipped   0 Failed   com.facebook.react.uimanager.SimpleViewPropertyTest
PASS     10.5s  1 Passed   0 Skipped   0 Failed   com.facebook.react.views.image.ImageResizeModeTest
PASS     12.5s  4 Passed   0 Skipped   0 Failed   com.facebook.react.views.image.ReactImagePropertyTest
PASS     12.3s  4 Passed   0 Skipped   0 Failed   com.facebook.react.CompositeReactPackageTest
PASS     12.2s  1 Passed   0 Skipped   0 Failed   com.facebook.react.RootViewTest
Updated test logs: buck-out/log/test.log
TESTS PASSED
```

Comment: Thank you. I can run tests now. Interestingly 89 of tests fail. Not sure if it's normal. Can you share your experience with failing tests. Thanks.

Comment: Definitely there is still something wrong there. 89 tests failing is not normal. I have zero failures here. I've updated the answer with the outcome of the tests. My advice is to look for one of the stack traces. You'll probably find out the reason for this amount of failures.